# Catch button press when mouse is over an element and not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show/hide button inside a table cell when ctrl is down and up and mouse is over and out of the element respectively. So, I wrote something like that:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 17)
        {
            showHideEditBtn(true);
        }
    });
    $(document).keyup(function (event) {
        if(event.which == 17)
        {
            showHideEditBtn(false)
        }
    });

    function showHideEditBtn(ctrlPressed)
    {
        var tableCell = $('.mouseoverbtn').parent();
        if (tableCell != '' && tableCell != undefined)
        {
            $(tableCell).mouseenter(function () {
                if(ctrlPressed)
                {
                    $(this).find('button').show();
                }
            });
            $(tableCell).mouseover(function () {
                if (!ctrlPressed) {
                    $(this).find('button').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).find('button').show();
                }
            });
            $(tableCell).mousemove(function () {
                if (!ctrlPressed) {
                    $(this).find('button').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).find('button').show();
                }
            });
            $(tableCell).mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).find('button').hide();
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that the button stays show or hidden when mouse is over the table cell but not moving. For example, if I move the button over this table cell with ctrl pressed, it shows the button, but when I release ctrl the button remains displayed even though the ctrl button is released and the same goes for the other way around. What can actually handle this when mouse is over the element but NOT moving.

P.S. when the coursor moves inside the table cell, it's all good.

Comment: You can't reliable detect whether the mouse is moving at the moment you press a button (or at the same moment when any event occurs).

Comment: @Teemu I don't need to detect that mouse is moving, I need to detect that it's positioned over the element

Comment: That's what your title says? Anyway, you've to re-think the entire logic, currently you're adding four new listeners every time user hits CTRL key, and four more when user releases CTRL key. Sooner or later your page will choke on the various events.

Comment: `event.cntrlKey` is what I think you want. By the way there is a way to detect if the mouse was moving when you press a button.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve it this way:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    var tableCell = $('.mouseoverbtn').parent();
    if(tableCell.length > 0 && (event.which == 17 || event.keyCode == 17))
    {
        tableCell.mouseover(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < tableCell.length; i++) {
                $(tableCell[i]).find('button').show();
            }
        });
        for (i = 0; i < tableCell.length; i++) {
            if ($(tableCell[i]).is(':hover')) {
                $(tableCell[i]).find('button').show();
            }
            else {
                $(tableCell[i]).find('button').hide();
            }
        }
    }
});
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    var tableCell = $('.mouseoverbtn').parent();
    if(tableCell.length > 0 && (event.which == 17 || event.keyCode == 17)) {
        tableCell.off('mouseenter');
        tableCell.off('mouseover');
        tableCell.find('button').hide();
    }
});
```

EDITED: if several elements have these buttons

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're just looking to do this?

```
var ok = false;
$(window).keydown(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey)ok = true;
});
$(window).keyup(){
  if(e.ctrlKey)ok = false;
});
$(tableCell).each(i, e){
  var t = $(e), b = t.find('button');
  t.mousedown(function(){
    if(ok)b.toggle();
  });
});
```